# How to get "Header -Section X-" in a page of word document with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, com-interop

As you see in [How to Use Multiple Headers and Footers in a Single Document](https://www.howtogeek.com/103481/how-to-use-multiple-headers-and-footers-in-a-single-document/), there is "Header -Section 1-", "Header -Section 2-", and so on. How can I get which header in the current range of word (my current range is current page).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
Word.Range myRange;
myRange = oDoc.Range(nStart, nEnd);
/*Determine header section*/
int nSectionX = 0; /*The X in Header -Section X-*/
foreach (Word.Section aSection in myRange.Sections)
{
    nSectionX = aSection.Index;
}
```

It turns out what I need all along is Word.Section.Index.